# C++ Static List of object pointers, and memory leak

Tags: c++, list, pointers, memory-leaks

I am trying to have a class that contains a static list of pointers to instances of the class, but I am getting a memory leak. I was wondering if anyone could point out what is wrong with the following code. I have a feeling its either to do with the destructor, or the `void creature::kill()` function. I note that I am using allegro but have not included some functions which are not doing anything special.

Firstly the class header:

```
class creature{


    private:    
        //some data for other functions


    public:
        static std::list<creature*> mycreatures; 

        creature(); 
        ~creature();                    

        void kill();


};
```

the class .cpp file

```
#include "creature.h"

std::list<creature*>creature::mycreatures;



creature::creature(){
    mycreatures.push_back(this);

}

creature::~creature(){

    std::list<creature*>::iterator p =
        find(mycreatures.begin(),mycreatures.end(),this);
    if(p != mycreatures.end()){
        mycreatures.erase(p);
    }   
}
void creature::kill(){
    if(mycreatures.size()>0){
    std::list<creature*>::iterator it = --mycreatures.end ( );
    delete (*it);
    }
}
```

and the main

```
#include "creature.h"

void main (void){  
     creature a;
     while(!key[KEY_ESC]){

        std::list<creature*>::iterator it;
        for(it=a.mycreatures.begin(); it!=a.mycreatures.end(); it++)
        {
         (*it)->//some other non included functions 
        }
        if(key[KEY_N]){
                    new creature();
    }
    if(key[KEY_K]){
        a.kill();
    }       
  }
  allegro_exit();
}
END_OF_MAIN();
```

Comment: What does `END_OF_MAIN()` do?

Comment: https://www.allegro.cc/manual/4/api/using-allegro/end_of_main

Comment: Does anything happen at all?

Comment: Also, you do `(*it)->//some other non included functions`: Does it mean you already had some instances of `creature` allocated?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't delete your objects using the iterator. Gain a reference to the desired object and delete this afterwards...

Comment: Maybe provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? This one is very bad style but does not show memleaks (if I comment out the noncompileable parts). Hint: make kill static. Don't use static members bia an instance, i.e. use `creature::mycreatures.begin()` etc. But better don't use that static list at all. -- maybe tell us about hte problem you are trying to solve with that list, we might have an alternative solution for you.

Comment: If you have a memory leak, it's probably not related to the code you posted. What's leaking?

Comment: As the code stands, it compiled fine and creates and destroys the objects, (at least they are no longer drawn by allegro). But a memory leak still occurs. also I am looking up the leak on task manager(noob) so If anyone has any useful links or help on good memory leak checking practice i would be most appreciative.

Comment: @user2103466 Task manager is an unreliable way to identify leaks - the C++ runtime doesn't always return deallocated memory to the OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 creature a;
```

Ack! You have code that calls `delete` on a creature without calling `new` on that creature. For this to work, you must *always* create `creature`s using `new` and never create them on the stack! What happens if this creature is killed while it's still in scope? Boom.

Comment: Between making me think about staic a bit more, the last guy who commented and deleted, (thanks) and your point about creature a; I got rid of a, and accessed the list directly through creature::mycreatures. and creature::kill. It seems to have fixed the problem, so thank you both